# How to build a report with nested subreports in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I'm looking to build an SSRS 2008 R2 report using the Report Builder, such that if a cell in a row of the report is clicked, it causes a hitherto hidden subreport to become visible, populated with data retrieved from a query which uses parameter values from the row of the cell clicked.

To explain further, the report should look like this before clicking:

```
|  Column 1  |  Column 2  |  Column 3  |  Column 4  |
|Row 1 Col 1 |Row 1 Col 2 |Row 1 Col 3 |Row 1 Col 4 |
|Row 2 Col 1 |Row 2 Col 2 |Row 2 Col 3 |Row 2 Col 4 |
|Row 3 Col 1 |Row 3 Col 2 |Row 3 Col 3 |Row 3 Col 4 |
|Row 4 Col 1 |Row 4 Col 2 |Row 4 Col 3 |Row 4 Col 4 |
```

Then after clicking `Row 1 Col 1`, the subreport with data from `Row A Col A` to `Row D Col D` should appear, as below:

```
|  Column 1  |  Column 2  |  Column 3  |  Column 4  |
|Row 1 Col 1 |Row 1 Col 2 |Row 1 Col 3 |Row 1 Col 4 |
    |  Column A  |  Column B  |  Column C  |  Column D  |
    |Row A Col A |Row A Col B |Row A Col C |Row A Col D |
    |Row B Col A |Row B Col B |Row B Col C |Row B Col D |
    |Row C Col A |Row C Col B |Row C Col C |Row C Col D |
    |Row D Col A |Row D Col B |Row D Col C |Row D Col D |
|Row 2 Col 1 |Row 2 Col 2 |Row 2 Col 3 |Row 2 Col 4 |
|Row 3 Col 1 |Row 3 Col 2 |Row 3 Col 3 |Row 3 Col 4 |
|Row 4 Col 1 |Row 4 Col 2 |Row 4 Col 3 |Row 4 Col 4 |
```

The data in the subreport will be populated from a query based on the values in `Row 1`.

Can anyone point me to where I can find out how to do this, or suggest how I might do it? Is it even possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

This [CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD) shows how to set up subreports. The example I think you want is the [Drilldown](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD#5) report.

Comment: I'm able to add subreports to the page of the main report, following the instructions at the page. However, the problem is that the report brings back ALL the data for the report, including the subreport data (or at least, it feels that way, as the report now takes longer to load). Is there a way I can load the subreport data on demand, rather than having it load when the main report data is loaded?

Comment: When l have set up sub reports or drill down reports l take a parameter from the main report. Pass that parameter to the data source used to build the sub report, such as a stored proceedure. So the data in the sub report is only what is required. See _(A) Creating a SubReport in SSRS_ in the CodeProject example for more details.
As to loading on demand. Looking [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/386a3868-514c-423c-907d-77b63f1b9ac4) if you have SSRS 2008 yes it is possible. I have used this before however not this way.